# Google Cloud Run and the JVM: how to save off heap dumps, thread dumps, gc logs on restart

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jvm, google-cloud-run

I want to be able to collect heap dumps, thread dumps, and gc logs from my JVM applications running in Cloud Run. I'm not sure how to collect these when my application is stopped, though - is there a way to send these three files to a Cloud Storage bucket or something?

Comment: Have a look to that blog post. You have a sigterm sent when the instance is of loaded and you have 10s to stop your app and to do all the things you want, for instance to send the file to Cloud Storage: https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/lifecycle-container-cloud-run

Comment: Ok I'll definitely take a look at that, thank you!

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere do you know if there's a way to collect gc logs or heap dumps or anything when the Cloud Run revision crashes, rather than when it gets shut down? That article you mentioned only goes over graceful shutdowns.

Comment: I have no idea about crash. I will ask the engineering team.

Comment: can you reach me out privately on LinkedIn or Twitter (gblaquiere). I will make you in connection with the Google Cloud Run engineering team

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere ok sounds good - just sent you an invitation on LinkedIn.